# cannot set obj value from model return

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
   public bool EditNew(News n)
   {
            News obj = new News();
            obj =   c.News.Where(p=>p.NewsID == n.NewsID).SingleOrDefault();
            obj.NewsTitle = n.NewsTitle;
            obj.IsActive = n.IsActive;
            obj.IsHot = n.IsHot;
            obj.NewsImage = n.NewsImage;
            c.SaveChanges();
            return true;
    }
```

Comment: i debugged obj but obj is null :( . i dont know why

Comment: i want to get obj to update

Comment: make sure `n.NewsID` has a value.. then make sure that value exists in your `News` table

Comment: `SingleOrDefault` returns null by default if it contains no results. Your object should contain query results if `NewsID` contains certain proper value to compare with and target results exist in database.

Comment: thank u every body :)

Comment: The `c` variable more likely pointed to an EF table context. Usually `using` statement provided to implement `Dispose` on the context.

Answer (score 0):

Not much information to go on, but assuming c is the `DbContext` object, it looks like you do not have a News object in your DB with the NewsId you are passing in to the EditNew method which results in the LINQ method `SingleOrDefault()` returning null